# Elixir: Access test helpers from dependency

Tags: testing, elixir

In the java-world, artifacts for a specific library often come in two flavors, one with and one without test helpers. Is there an equivalent in the Elixir-world?

Specifically, I would like to be able to expose mocks or data generators in an application `A`. Application `B` now depends on `A` and gains the ability to use the exposed helpers from `A` in its own tests. Now, I do not want those helpers to appear anywhere in production, so they should only be included when specifically asked for (e.g. by `MIX_ENV=test`).

EDIT: Essentially, the question comes down to: "How to make tests from `A` available for the tests of `B`?"

Comment: I really can't understand what you're asking for here--can you maybe reword your question a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago, I found a working solution: I extend `elixirc_paths` specifically for the `:test` environment and put shared helpers into another directory within the application (e.g. `test/support`). In `mix.exs`:

```
def project do
  [
  # ...
  elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
  ]
end

defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]
```

Then, depending applications can use the modules in `test/support` when they compile the application in the test environment.